# How to MAP select stored procedure in Entity Framework 6 code-first approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

For example when we write

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblError>().MapToStoredProcedures();
}
```

Then it will create 3 stored procedures in the database with the names of
`tblError_Delete`, `tblError_Insert`, `tblError_Update`

My question is about `tblError_Select`: how to map a stored procedure that is used to execute select queries?

I want EF to be generate `tblError_Select` along with preceding 3 stored procedures.

I want to do CRUD operation using stored procedures with EF. Currently I can do Insert, Update, Delete but what about Select? Why does EF not create a stored procedure for `Select` operation?

Comment: i suppose you are right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Consider updating your post with more details so as to make it relevant for this platform.

Comment: @nyedidikeke i am very specific to my question, How to perform select operation using SP in EF. Do i need to manually write a SP for select queries?

Comment: How could EF *possibly* know how and what you want to select? Sometimes you might need all columns - other times just a few of the table's columns. Sometimes you want all rows - sometimes you filter the rows by one column, other times by another, and yet another time by both. It's just not **feasible** to create **ONE** globally useful `SELECT` stored procedure - therefore, EF doesn't attempt to do so. If you **must use** stored procedures to select (***why?!??!?***), then you must write them yourself

Comment: then how to create manually..

Comment: @sushilsuthar i think he means you have to create it within sql itself, when you run your code once and database is created then you can create one manually and map it using : DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedureName",params);

Comment: I need to do the same as the original question (what is not answered in the selected answer). This is: to say to EF to use a SP to populate entries of an Entity defined in the model with DbSet<T>, any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question brought some new insights, I've researched a little and marc_s answered helped. Basically Knowing EF Code-First, when you do not have any database it is kinda impossible to create a SP for Select, since you have to create the database first then insert data within then select what is there (which makes more sense), you have to create the Stored Procedure within the SQL and use code below to run it:
You can call a stored procedure in your `DbContext` class as follows.

```
this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityType>("storedProcedure‌​Name",params);
```

Credit goes to @Marc_S and [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx)